# Sort NSDictionary of Months by the proper month order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a nsdictionary that looks something like this (Key | Value):

"Apr" = "April"
"Dec" = "December"
"Jan" = "January"
...etc.

What I need to is "sort" this dictionary so that when I pass it to a UIPicker the months are in the proper order in which they occur (i.e. Jan, Feb, March, April, May, etc.) How can I accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI - Such an approach will make it really hard to support other languages in your app. Why not use the `NSDateFormatter` methods such as `monthSymbols` and `shortMonthSymbols` to get the months names, already in order, and in the user's language without any need to add your own dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered and cannot be sorted.

You will need to keep a separate `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` of dictionary keys, sorted by dictionary values.  Then use this to determine the order in which to retrieve values from the dictionary.